# Entity Framework, Make SystemVersioning Columns as NotMapped for Temporal tables Automatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Entity Framework does not seem to handle System Versioning columns well (StartDate, EndDate) for temporal tables. When we scaffold a database automatically, we want to place SystemVersioning Columns as `NotMapped`. Is there a parameter in commandline to make System Versioning Columns automatically as not mapped? Company literally 1000s of tables, and need way to make them automatically NotMapped, everytime we rescaffold. Scaffolding is done very week.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
```

Comment: Are you scaffolding from a database project? In that case EF Core Power Tools may be able to assist

Comment: hi @ErikEJ we are scaffolding from existing database in localhost, however we have database project also

Comment: Do you want the columns no mapped or rather not scaffolded at all?

Comment: hi @ErikEJ both options are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the columns HIDDEN, and they will not be scaffolded.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] ALTER COLUMN [StartDate] ADD HIDDEN;
```

[hide a column from table in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263621/hide-a-column-from-table-in-ms-sql-server)